# Cortex M0 or M3 serial interface to ARM7

Tags: cortex-m, arm7

I have worked on ARM7 controller (LPC2138) for my application. But now to add NFC module I am using LPC1227 controller along with NFC chip. ( Both dies in single package )

Now, if I want to communicate between these two controllers( Cortex M0/M3 and LPC2138 ), Is there any issue ( communication related ) if one will be higher end module ( either cortex-M0 or M3 )?

Both controllers will be interfaced with I2C or UART interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there will be no issue.  Use a uart at each end, this will be easier to get working than i2c.

If you think about it, the world is absolutely filled with kit which talks together over i2c and uarts which comes from different manufacturers.